# Disable anti-aliasing in Chrome / Webkit

Tags: performance, google-chrome, webkit, interpolation, antialiasing

Is there a way to disable antialiasing for images in Chrome/Webkit? For performance reasons, I'd like to not have the browser smooth images larger than the actual files.

[Image interpolation mode in Chrome/Safari?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5403955/image-interpolation-mode-in-chrome-safari) mentions this problem from a year and a half ago, so hopefully Webkit has added some sort of support since then.

Edit: Upon further research, [Using nearest-neighbor with CSS zoom on canvas (and img)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028864/using-nearest-neighbor-with-css-zoom-on-canvas-and-img) seems to go further into this, but isn't clear on exactly what works.