# Image quality issues with downscaled images on Chrome but not Firefox?

Tags: html, css, image, cross-browser, scaling

I have large images (728px by 546px) that I need to downscale in a browser (to width:179px and height:auto).

When I do this in Firefox, the results looks great.  But when I do this in Chrome, the exact same code and images looks different and far inferior.

Is there a trick to making downscaled images look better in Chrome?

Here is a Fiddle example...if you look at the leaves in the foreground, or the front deck hatch you'll see they look much better in Firefox:

```
<img src='http://www.wisconsinrivertrips.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/DSCN0544.jpg' style='width:179px;height:auto' />
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qr067gg9/

Here is also a screenshot of the two side by side:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wAIAb.png

Comment: Can confirm this is still an issue with Chrome. Firefox, for its faults, does a way better job at rendering images.

Comment: Still an issue, in my case, if I downscale lossy compressed jpeg, it became too pixelated being the worst with images with texts.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a bug in Chrome. See [here](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/VezviJoWRsI)

And a possible workaround from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3900436/image-scaling-by-css-is-there-a-webkit-alternative-for-moz-crisp-edges) question:

```css
img {
  width: 179px;
  height: auto;
}

.crisp {
  image-rendering:-webkit-optimize-contrast;
}
```

```html
<img src='http://www.wisconsinrivertrips.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/DSCN0544.jpg' />

<img class="crisp" src='http://www.wisconsinrivertrips.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/DSCN0544.jpg' />
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I did try "image-rendering:-webkit-optimize-contrast;", but in most cases the small images turned out way too jagged, so this won't work.  The firefox images still look far superior.

Comment: Have you considered loading multiple image sizes at their natural resolution depending on a media query? In other words, the browser is not resizing anything.

Comment: Yes, I have considered this.   However, for an assortment of reasons, this is unfortunately not feasible in my case.

Comment: Fair enough, I guess if it's a bug there aren't a huge amount of options. Best of luck

Comment: is it really a bug? why aren't they fixing it? anyway this does work